# Can't set Sony image ratings via windows explorer

Tags: metadata, sony, windows

I'm having issues changing metadata for photos from 1 camera.

When I load photos from my camera (Nikon D7000) I can use the details bar at the bottom of windows explorer to add tags, change star rating and adjust dates if I want.

With my wife's camera a Sony Cybershot DSC-WX200 all these details appear to be locked, I can't add tags or rate photos.  Does anyone know how this could be unlocked.

I'd prefer to do it in windows explorer and not use some other software at this moment.

thanks.

Comment: What format(s) are the Nikon and Sony images?  JPG, raw..?

Comment: both of them are jpg

Comment: Are the files on the hard drive, or on the card?

Comment: The files are all on the hard drive running windows 7